# risolto problema "itunes cannot run because some of its are missing . please reinstall itunes"

Tags: itunes

Buongiorno oggi aggiornando Itunes mi è apparsa una finestra di errore
itunes cannot run because some of its are missing . please reinstall itunes
dopo avere disinstallato e reinstallato mille volte ho risolto scaricando una versione precedente di Itunes adesso funziona correttamente e aspetto che venga corretto il bug
buona giornata

Comment: Normalmente, facciamo domande in inglese. E non rispondiamo loro nello stesso campo. C'è un link separato per le risposte.

Comment: Did you report the alleged bug to Apple?  I’ve installed every version for years without that happening.  Also, did you know that you can tell the system to issue error messages in Italian?

Comment: The other post's answer was to fix it by changing interface language in Windows from Italian to English.  Since Luciano's error message is in English, that's not the answer to his issue.  Besides, we don't even know if he's using Windows.  I could translate the post to English, but since it still needs clarity, I don't see any reason to do so nor to re-open.  However, I don't think it's a duplicate.